# Select rectangular plotting area in google-chart scatter chart

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I am using angular and google-chart for drawing charts on WEB GUI; I would like to allow user to select a rectangular area of chart and zooming that zone. How can I do that using ? Is it not possible with google-chart, can you suggest another free visualisation tool that supports that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i *believe* the [configuration option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) you're looking for is --> `explorer`

this will provide the default explorer behavior, enabling users to pan horizontally and vertically by dragging, and to zoom in and out by scrolling.

```
explorer: {}
```

use the following to allow zoom by dragging across a rectangular area

```
explorer: {
  actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset']
}
```

**note**: the option only works with [continuous axes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#discrete-vs-continuous) (such as numbers or dates).